# GAPI VS Standard HTTP Rest Call

Tags: rest, reactjs, google-app-engine, vue.js, google-cloud-endpoints

What is the recommended way of connecting to the Google EndPoint API?

1. Use the Google provided gapi js library -  `gapi.client.load('helloworld', 'v1', callback, apiRoot);`
2. Call the REST endpoints directly - `https://project-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/myapi/v1/users`
3. Is there a better way?

I'm looking to integrate Google Endpoints with ReactJs or VueJs

Answer (score 0):

The gapi js library is going to have all of the headers that you need for the application to work properly. It effectively abstracts out a lot of the configuration that you would have to do to your HTTP Library. Then your library can be configured for your api. For example, lets say you have authentication built into your app and you are authenticating via api tokens. Well, if Google uses the same thing, then you have to change your libraries configuration each time you query the api. The same thing goes for Google Analytics, Google Maps, and Facebook OAuth API.